# How to correctly reformulate the universal property of the direct sum of abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060492/835419) I learned that if $G$ is an abelian group we may state (without diagrams) the universal property of the direct sum of finitely many abelian groups by saying that that map from there is a group isomoprhism between $\prod \mathrm{Hom}(G_i,G)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(G_1\times\cdots\times G_n,G)$. I would like to know if it is essential to say that the map is a group isomorphism. I was looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096752/question-about-universal-property-of-direct-sum-of-abelian-groups) post and I think that we just need that map between $\prod \mathrm{Hom}(G_i,G)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(G_1\times\cdots\times G_n,G)$ to be bijective. Why would we also need it to be a group homomorphism? I know it is, but is it truly necessary to say that when writing down the universal property?

Comment: Consider the statement: If $G_1,...,G_n$ and $H$ are abelian groups such that 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \;\Bigl| \mathrm{Hom}(G_i,G)\Bigr|
=
\Bigl|
\mathrm{Hom}(H,G)
\Bigr|
$$
holds for all abelian groups $G$, then
$$
H\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n G_i
$$
Is this your claim?

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary. When an object satisfies some universal property, that means that it is an initial or terminal object of some category. But the group structure on $\text{Hom}(G,H)$ is not part of the structure of the category of abelian groups. This additional group structure is the result of all abelian groups being group objects in the category of groups, so the fact that the map you described is an isomorphism is an additional property, and not really part of the definition.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure that I get this basic things right.